# Why is the Negative Binomial typically preferred over the Poisson?

Tags: poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

I know that the Poisson is a special type of negative binomial, but from some shallow readings I've noticed that people claim that the Negative Binomial is better than the Poisson as it accounts for empirical distributions with more variance.

Can someone give me a concrete answer on why the Negative Binomial is preferred?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the other way around, namely that the NB is a subset of the Poisson. The key assumption for the Poisson is that the variance equals the mean, whereas for the NB, the variance is greater than the mean. This is usually empirically determined as opposed to being a subjective preference.

Comment: According to the Limit Proof on Wikipedia, I believe the Poisson is the subset of the NB. Though, I'm not so certain

Comment: Maybe so but that's not how McCullagh and Nelder treat them...http://www.amazon.com/Generalized-Edition-Monographs-Statistics-Probability/dp/0412317605

Comment: As @DJohnson mentioned, choice of NB vs. Poisson is empirically determined.  The test on the statistical significance of the dispersion parameter ($\alpha$) in your NB output will tell you whether you should report NB or Poisson results.  There are other flavors of NB and Poisson if you care to read further, such as the zero-inflated models.  There are also formal statistical tests that will tell you which results to report.